# Flatten an array by only one level without using .flat()

Tags: javascript

How can I flatten an array without using `flat()` by 1 level?

So far I have this

```
function flatten(array) {
  let flattened = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const current = array[i];
    for (let j = 0; i < current.length; j++) {
      flattened.push(current[j])
    }
  }
  return flattened
}

console.log(flatten([['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux']]));
// -> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
flatten([[1], [2], 3, 4, [5]]);
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
flatten([false, [true, [false]], [true]]);
// -> [false, true, [false], true]
flatten([]);
// -> []
```

and its crashing my memory

Comment: `for (let j = 0; i < current.length; j++) {` here you have an infinite loop. if `i < current.length`  is true, It won't ever change (inside that loop). so the inner loop is doing `flattened.push(current[j])` untill something crashes.

Comment: ... personal opinion ... in terms of simplicity, readability and thus, beauty, only approaches that read like that ... `... .reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), [])` ... should be candidates for the accepted answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) (check out the non-accepted answers)

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps

```js
var twoDimension = [[1], [2], 3, 4, [5]];

var plano = twoDimension.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el), []);

console.log(plano);
```

Comment: what is concat doing here? and what is the [] doing at the 2nd parameter?

Comment: @sonEtLumiere `Array.reduce` takes 2 arguments, a callback function and an initial value.

Answer (score 5):

To flatten by a single level only, [`Array#concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) can be leveraged. It accepts any amount of arguments, so an array can be [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into the function call:

```
[].concat(...arr)
```

This avoids any explicit loops. JavaScript handles everything:

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  return [].concat(...arr);
}

console.log(flatten([['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux']]));
// -> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
console.log(flatten([[1], [2], 3, 4, [5]]));
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(flatten([false, [true, [false]], [true]]));
// -> [false, true, [false], true]
console.log(flatten([]));
// -> []
```

Comment: this will fail in nested array : let nestedArr = [1, [2, 3], [[4, 5, 6], 7]];

Comment: @MonuRohilla I've explicitly stated this is for single level flattening. And the examples do show that multi-level nesting still leaves nested elements. I have no idea why you say it "fails" when it's an explicit goal of the question itself.

Comment: by the way is their any way to flat the nested array? 
i found your solution helpful but it fails on nested array that's why i said 'fails'

Comment: @MonuRohilla [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10865025) - `arr.flat(Infinity)`

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Array.reduce` and the `spread syntax`:

```js
function flatten(array) {
  return array.reduce(
    (accumulator, item) => {
      // if `item` is an `array`,
      // use the `spread syntax` to 
      // append items of the array into 
      // the `accumulator` array
      if (Array.isArray(item)) {
        return [...accumulator, ...item];
      }
      // otherwise, return items in the 
      // accumulator plus the new item
      return [...accumulator, item];
    }
  , []); // initial value of `accumulator`
}

console.log(flatten([['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux']]));
// -> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
console.log(flatten([[1], [2], 3, 4, [5]]));
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(flatten([false, [true, [false]], [true]]));
// -> [false, true, [false], true]
console.log(flatten([]));
// -> []
```

References:

- [Array.reduce - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Spread syntax - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Comment: what does if (Array.isArray(item)) mean?

Comment: @americanguy93 I added comments with explanations, but this basically checks if the item in the array is another array, and if so, it takes it's items and combines it with the final array

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method if your array have primitive data type and want to flat it completely:

```
arr.toString().split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Using Recursion

    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6, [6, 7], 7, 8]]
    
    let arr2 = [];
    function flat(arr) {
         arr.forEach(element => {
              if (typeof (element) == 'object') {
                   flat(element);
              } else {
                   arr2.push(element);
              }
         });
    }
    
    flat(arr);
    
    console.log(arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **reducer** of javascript as an alternative to flat().

```
const arr = [1, 2, [3, 4]];

arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), []);
// [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or you can use decomposition syntax

```
const flattened = arr => [].concat(...arr);
```

For more details, go to [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose given flatten number list without using the flat function is:

```
let array = [2,3,[5,2,[6,[3, [4, 5, [5, 1, 3]]]],1,1],9];
//let array= [2,3,[5,2,[6,[3, [4, 5, [5, {"key":"value"}, 3]]]],1,1],9]; 
//achieve above commented nested array condition using second approach.
```

The best answer already given by @Mahipal that would be first approach i.e.

```
array.toString().split(',')
```

with number array conversion

```
array.toString().split(',').map(n => +n)
```

another approach would be using function recursion without `toString()`

```
function flatter(arr) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) && (!isNaN(arr) || typeof arr === "object")) {
    return arr;
  }
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
   a.push(...[].concat(flatter(b)));
   return a; 
  }, [])
}

flatter(array);
```

and output is:

```
[ 2, 3, 5, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 9 ]
```

Hope this would help many ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use spread operator with reduce.

```js
function flatten(array) {

   return array.reduce((a,v) => [...a, ...(Array.isArray(v) ? v : [v])], []);
}

console.log(flatten([['foo', 'bar'], 'baz', 'qux']))
```

Comment: what does the ...a ...v mean here?

Comment: `...` is the spread operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: Please consider editing or erasing this code. This purely (unguarded) spread operator based approach fails already for flattening `[[1,2,3], 4,5,6]`. Have a look at the solution of *goto1*.

Comment: @PeterSeliger i have added an check to check if its an array

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
for (let j = 0; i < current.length; j++) {
//              ^ wrong variable, should be j
```

And you need to check if the value is not an array, then just push the current value and continue the loop.

```js
function flatten(array) {
  let flattened = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const current = array[i];
    if (!Array.isArray(current)) {
        flattened.push(current);
        continue;
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < current.length; j++) {
      flattened.push(current[j])
    }
  }
  return flattened
}

console.log(flatten([['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 'qux']]));
// -> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
console.log(flatten([[1], [2], 3, 4, [5]]));
// -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
console.log(flatten([false, [true, [false]], [true]]));
// -> [false, true, [false], true]
console.log(flatten([]));
// -> []
```

Comment: Is using `continue` instead of an if else loop a better practice, or just a preference?

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo where in your innermost loop you set i to 0 instead of j. The only other thing you needed to do was check to see if each element in the outer array was scalar (not an array) and push it to the returned array if so.

```js
function flatten(arr) {
  let flat = []
  for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const cur = arr[i]
    if(!Array.isArray(cur)){
      flat.push(cur)
    }else{
      for (let j=0; j < cur.length; j++) {
        flat.push(cur[j])
      }
    }
  }
  return flat
}

console.log(flatten([['foo','bar'],['baz','qux']]))
console.log(flatten([[1],[2],3,4,[5]]))
console.log(flatten([false,[true,[false]],[true]]))
console.log(flatten([]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Following could be used as a general implementation of Array.prototype.flat()

```js
function flattenArray(arr, depth = 1) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return [arr];
  }
  return depth > 0
    ? arr.reduce(
        (acc, curr) =>
          acc.concat(
            Array.isArray(curr) ? flattenArray(curr, depth - 1) : curr
          ),
        []
      )
    : arr.slice();
}

const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const b = "a";
const c = [1, [2, 3], 4];
const d = [1, [2, [3, 4], 5], 6];
const e = [1, [2, [3, [4, [5], [6]], 7], 8], 9];
console.log(flattenArray(a, Infinity));
console.log(flattenArray(b, Infinity));
console.log(flattenArray(c, Infinity));
console.log(flattenArray(d, Infinity));
console.log(flattenArray(e, Infinity));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another interesting way to do it.

1. Stringify the array
2. remove all array start symbol ([) and array end symbol(])
3. Add array start symbol at the beginning and array end symbol at the end.
4. Now parse the resulting string

const arr2 = [0, 1, 2, [5, [10, [3, 4]]]]

```
const arr2 = [0, 1, 2, [5, [10, [3, 4]]]]
console.log( JSON.parse('['+ JSON.stringify(arr2).replace(/\[/g, ' ').replace(/\]/g, ' ') + ']'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var multiDimensionArray = [["a"],["b","c"],["d"]]; //array of arrays
var flatArray = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], multiDimensionArray); //flatten array of arrays
console.log(flatArray);
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Comment: That's just [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62750495/), isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    function myFlattern(arr) {
  let check;
  do{
    check=false;
    for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
      if(Array.isArray(arr[i]))
      {
        check=true;
        let x=arr[i];
        arr.splice(i,1,...x);        
      }
    }

  }while(check)
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = [1,[3,5],[6,8],[3,[0,9],7],4];

let flattened = [];
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  const current = array[i];
  if (!Array.isArray(current)) {
      flattened.push(current);
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < current.length; j++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(current[j])){
        flattened.push(current[j]);
    }else if (Array.isArray(current[j])){
        let newle = current[j]
        flattened.push(newle[0]);
        flattened.push(newle[1]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(flattened);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
//For infinite nested array
const ar =[1,2,[3,[4,5,[6,7,[8,9]]]]]
 function flatten(ar) {
 return ar.reduce((ac, cur) =>{
   if(Array.isArray(cur)){
     return [...ac, ...flatten(cur)]
   }
   return [...ac, cur];
 },[])
}
console.log(flatten(ar))
```

Answer (score -1):

A possible alternative would be **without using flat()**:

```
var arr = [['object1', 'object2'],['object1'],['object1','object2','object3']];

var flattened = [].concat.apply([],arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to forget about the depth of nesting:

```
let multiArr = [1, [1, 2, [3, 4]], [2, 4, [45, 98]]];
  while (multiArr.find((elem) => Array.isArray(elem))) {
  multiArr = [].concat.apply([], multiArr);
}
console.log(multiArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Everyone have different approach some are really good but here's one I learn durring leetcode and it have very less affect on memory and better runtime then other. Explanation: Goal is to achieve the functionality like Array.flat() without using it. Bellow function will take two parameter one is array and the second is the depth of flantening you want to achieve ( just like Array.flat(2). It will flanten two level depth of array and leaving the rest if any.). Inside a funtion there's a helper function which take index **value** and intial depth which is zer0. If the **value** is non array object then it will pushed into new result array. Otherwise it will call itself again with increment of depth level. This process of recursion keep running until depth is remain less then the funtion's second argument.

PS: I determine the runtime and memory performance from the leetcode.

```js
var flat = function (arr, n) {
    const res = [];

    function helper(arr,depth) {
        for(const val of arr) {
            if(typeof(val) === 'object' && depth < n) {
                helper(val,depth + 1);
            } else {
                res.push(val);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
    return helper(arr,0);
};

console.log(flat([1,2,3,[4,5,6],[7,8,[9,10,11],12],[13,14,15]],2));
// Expected output [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,  13, 14, 15]
console.log(flat([1,2,3,[4,5,6],[7,8,[9,10,11],12],[13,14,15]],1));
//Expected output [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, [ 9, 10, 11 ], 12, 13, 14, 15 ];
```

Comment: The second `console.log` stills has an array in the array...

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'll try to explain the code